Daf Yomi & Mishna Yomi Coinciding
On 18 Kislev 5785 (Thursday Dec 19, 2024),
both Daf Yomi & Mishna Yomi will be starting Sanhedrin.
Have these two learning programs ever perfectly coincided before?
Also wondering the last times they at least overlapped?

Friday, Sept 27, 2024 (Elul 24, 5784) had a different kind of convergence.
The daf was Bava Basra 94. The Mishnayot in Mishna Yomi were Bava Metzia 3:3-4.
The daf, at the top of amud B, quotes BM 3:4. I don't recall any other such match-up, at least not since the beginning of this cycle of Mishna Yomi.

This happened again on November 20, 2024 (Cheshvan 19, 5785). The daf yomi, Bava Basra daf 148b, references the halacha in the mishna yomi, Bava Basra 4:1, where it discusses ownership of a fenced-in roof after sale of the home. Granted, this is probably more likely since both daf yomi and mishna yomi are in the same maseches.

Thanks for this first contribution! It's very cool, and I can see why it inspired you to make your first answer after 13 years :) You are indeed very cool too. Shabbat Shalom

Thanks, but I haven't been on Mi Yodeya that long. I've been on Stackoverflow that long -- though I would've assumed that to be longer, actually. /shrug G'mar Tov!
